# Intellij Fails to Import SBT project

Tags: java, scala, sbt, intellij-14, playframework-2.4

I am trying to import sbt project to intellij 14 but, This is what I get when I open a project:

Error:Error while importing SBT project:
...

```
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:70)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:65)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:65)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:48)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:32)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:24)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:53)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/karthik/Play2.4/Directory/target/.history 
(Permission denied)
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

See complete log in `/home/karthik/.IdeaIC14/system/log/sbt.last.log`

This is my sbt.last.log file

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support 
was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from /home/karthik/Play2.4/Rocket_Singh/project
[info] Set current project to Rocket_Singh 
(in build file:/home/karthik/Play2.4/Rocket_Singh/)
[Rocket_Singh] $ java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/home/karthik/Play2.4/Rocket_Singh/target/.history (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at jline.console.history.FileHistory.flush(FileHistory.java:87)
    at sbt.JLine.readLineWithHistory(LineReader.scala:28)
    at sbt.JLine.sbt$JLine$$unsynchronizedReadLine(LineReader.scala:19)
    at sbt.JLine$$anonfun$readLine$1.apply(LineReader.scala:16)
    at sbt.JLine$$anonfun$readLine$1.apply(LineReader.scala:16)
    at sbt.JLine$$anonfun$withJLine$1.apply(LineReader.scala:114)
    at sbt.JLine$$anonfun$withJLine$1.apply(LineReader.scala:112)
    at sbt.JLine$.withTerminal(LineReader.scala:86)
    at sbt.JLine$.withJLine(LineReader.scala:112)
    at sbt.JLine.readLine(LineReader.scala:16)
    at sbt.BasicCommands$$anonfun$shell$1.apply(BasicCommands.scala:164)
    at sbt.BasicCommands$$anonfun$shell$1.apply(BasicCommands.scala:160)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$command$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Command.scala:29)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$command$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Command.scala:29)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:92)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:91)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:70)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:65)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:65)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:48)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:32)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:24)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:53)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/home/karthik/Play2.4/Rocket_Singh/target/.history (Permission denied)
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Comment: So, could you include complete log from /home/karthik/.IdeaIC14/system/log/sbt.last.log? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/home/karthik/Play2.4/Directory/target/.history (Permission denied)
/home/karthik/Play2.4/Rocket_Singh/target/.history (Permission denied)
```

These messages indicate that you don't have permission to access these paths. Check if the user running intellij has write permissions on `.history`. In Linux you do that by :

```
cd /home/karthik/Play2.4/Directory/target/
ls -l
```

If `.history` is a file the response would be something like

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 karthik karthik  961 Aug 30 18:26 .history
```

with the `rw` indicating read and write and the 2 names being user name and group name

Comment: When i checked permissions are like this. what i need to do now? -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 29 Aug 31 12:50 .history

Comment: that means that only root is able to write in this folder. I assume you have logged in and run intellij as karthik. Is there a reason why you have these files owned by root ? I would recommend changing ownership of the Play2.4 folder to your username. e.g. `sudo chown -R karthik:karthik  /home/karthik/Play2.4`. I would not recommend running Intellij as root.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same issue, and as Manos Nikolaidis suggested the issue is with file permissions.
To resolve this issue quickly, I tried to run the idea with root user permissions and I was able to import the project normally.

The command I used to do that is here (from idea root/bin directory):

```
sudo ./idea.sh
```